# How to prove using only statistical mechanics and canonical probabilities that $F=U-TS$

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am a little confused, I would like to prove that :

$$ F=U-TS $$

Using only the fact that :

$$ F=-k_b T ln(Z) $$
$$P(\sigma)=\frac{e^{-\beta} E(\sigma)}{Z}$$

$$S(E)=k_b ln(\Omega(E))$$

What I mean by using only stat mech is that I don't want to use the classical thermodynamic relation saying $S=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$.

Is it possible ?

Actually I ended up with either :

$$F=-k_bTln(\sum_E e^{-\beta(E-TS(E))})$$

Or : $$<E>=F+\beta \frac{\partial F}{\partial \beta} $$

But I don't know how to end up with $F=U-TS$ where $U=<E>$ without using the classical thermodynamic relation $S=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$

Is what I want possible or we are forced to use classical thermodynamic to conclude ?

Comment: What you want to do is basically impossible without considering a specific Hamiltonian. If you want to do it for, say, the ideal gas, then it is possible.

Comment: @valerio ok, so we are forced to use the classical thermodynamic relations to be able to conclude in a general case (or we can only do statistical mechanics but we have to be in a specific example). Thank you

Comment: Maybe with some enormous mathematical effort you can prove that that is true for any reasonable $\mathcal H$, but it is much easier to invoke the thermodynamic relations and then show *a posteriori* that the results agree with the definitions of statistical mechanics.

Comment: @StarBucK You can actually conclude quite generally from what you already wrote: the sum over $E$ in the expression you derived for $F$ will be essentially concentrated on the largest term, corresponding to, say, $E_*$. This can be made precise, of course. This immediately leads to $F=E_*-TS(E_*)$. Of course, you should still argue that the value $E_*$ you get is the internal energy (for example, showing that it is essentially equal to the average energy in the canonical ensemble, which is true for more or less the same reason).

Comment: $E,S\sim N$ so if $N \rightarrow\infty $ and $E-TS(E)$ under the exponent has a minimum at some $E_m$,   we can apply *Laplace's method* for approximating sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding regarding entropy. Given a probability distribution $P(\sigma)$, the **statistical entropy** is defined as
     $$S[P]=-k_B\sum_\sigma P(\sigma)\ln P(\sigma)$$
The extremum of this quantity with the only constrain that $\sum_\sigma P(\sigma)=1$ leads to the microcanonical ensemble
      $$P_{\rm micro}[\sigma]={1\over \Omega(E)}$$
Plugging this into the statistical entropy gives the **microcanonical entropy**
     $$S_{\rm micro}=k_B\ln\Omega(E)$$

The extremum of the statistical entropy with the constrains that $\sum_\sigma P(\sigma)=1$ and that the average energy is $\langle E\rangle$ leads to the canonical ensemble
     $$P_{\rm can.}[\sigma]={1\over{\cal Z}}e^{-\beta E}$$
Plugging this into the statistical entropy gives the **canonical entropy**
     $$S_{\rm can.}=-k_B\sum_\sigma P[\sigma]
 \big(-\ln{\cal Z}-\beta E\big)$$
You can recognize canonical averages so
      $$S_{\rm can.}=k_B\ln{\cal Z}+k_B\beta\langle E\rangle$$
from which follows
      $$-k_BT\ln{\cal Z}=F=\langle E\rangle-TS_{\rm can.}$$

Comment: Such an approach is fine, but, strictly speaking, it still requires a proof that the two entropies defined here (microcanonical and canonical) coincide in the thermodynamic limit if you want to recover the OP's claim.

Comment: My guess was that @StarBucK did not realize that he mixed quantities from different statistical ensembles (partition function from canonical ensemble and microcanonical entropy) so I tried to show in the answer that $F=E-TS$ can be recovered by sticking to the canonical ensemble. As an additional step, I agree that you can invoke the equivalence of ensemble in the thermodynamic limit.

Answer (score 0):

For me the most satisfying "proof" is using Liouville's Theorem. Simplifying, using Poisson Brackets, and for a system in statistical equilibrium (recall that Liouville's theorem is nothing more than partial differential chain rule on H, a function of the phase space),

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=-\{\rho, H\}=0$$

One such solution (on the interval $E=H$),

$$\rho(E) = Ae^{-E/kT}=e^{(F-E)/kT}$$
Gives,
$$kT\ln \rho=F-E$$
And since $S=-k\ln \rho$ (easy to show this from microcanonical ensemble),
$$-ST=F-E$$